# Make dynamic div elements collapse like collapsable headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking to achieve something like [this demo here](http://line25.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/header-effect/final-demo/index.html), but for each element of a class, it will stop scrolling and drag the next div up from the bottom. This could be a similar thing to a printer printing paper. I'm not sure how it will fully work for the JS side but what I have is below. I'm close, but it doesn't like doing more than 2 elements. Adding the support for the extra elements would be amazing because then this could be released as a library to achieve the effect.

If the below snippet doesn't look like it works quite right view it [here on codepen](http://codepen.io/austinkregel/pen/WbGjKm).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.container:first-child').css('position', 'relative');
});
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('.container').each(function(i) {
    var winheight = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
    var distToTop = $(this).position().top + $(this).height();
    var dist = distToTop - winheight;
    if ((dist) <= 0) {
      $(this).css('position', 'fixed').css('top', ($(this).children().height() - $(window).height()) / (-2) + 'px');

    } else if (dist == $(this).height()) {
      $(this).css('position', 'relative').css('top', $(window).height() + 'px').css('z-index','1');
    }
    console.log(dist + ' ' + i);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100%;
}
.container:first-child {
  background: tan;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.container:nth-child(2) {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='big'>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='t'>
      <img src='http://placehold.it/500x250'>
      <img src='http://placehold.it/500x250'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='t2'>
      <img src='http://placehold.it/500x250/fff'>
      <img src='http://placehold.it/500x250/fff'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='t'>
      <img src='http://placehold.it/500x250'>
      <img src='http://placehold.it/500x250'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='t2'>
      <img src='http://placehold.it/500x250/fff'>
      <img src='http://placehold.it/500x250/fff'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The Demo on this site is currently a little wonky because of the difference in windows sizes.

Comment: Update on this, I found out I was overthinking this WAY too much... I didn't realize that they were just background images with a fixed position. Once I found that out it became SOOOO much easier... xD